# Best way to search Mysql - large where or multiple where statements

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

Im just looking for the best way to go about building this code for search query.

Say I have a search that has to search for 6 columns and an advance search that looks at 14 columns.
I was thinking of compressing it to search 1 column with a large number.

So for example say I have categories 'city, price, date, type, area' then about 8 'yes' or 'no' (or 1/0) columns. I am just wondering which search would work better/faster.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE city=$city AND price BETWEEN ($price) AND other_searchables = [3-9][2-9]__1_1_110110_____1_1
```

With this code the custom fields are put into one field and given 0=no or 1=yes and the beginning searches to see if the first 2 numbers equal 3+ and 2+ then _ for any characters. So for example other_searchables field would look like '2300111011011100000101'

OR use WHERE for each column?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE city=$city AND price BETWEEN ($price) AND type = $types AND area = $areas AND customfield = 1 AND customfield = 0 AND customfield = 1 AND customfield = 1 AND customfield = 0 AND customfield = 1 AND customfield = 0 AND customfield = 1
```

I am going to index city as this will be searched everytime... Just looking for any advice on which way to go here as far as which query would be better.

Thanks

Comment: Actually you can do a benchmark under `EXPLAIN` statement.

Comment: Will this work with a low amount of rows in the table, I will put together both codes and see which is faster within the next few days and report back if so